# DB2 SQL SELECT top 1 group with join

Tags: sql, db2

I'm connecting to a DB2 database and want to use the Max(PO180M1.POORDT) or the TOP 1 grouping by the PO180M2.PHPPN (PARTNO). How would I do this? I think I keep getting close but not getting it to work.

```
SELECT PO180M2.PHPPN AS PartNo, (PO180M2.PHVNPD || ' ' || PO180M2.PHVNP2) AS PartDesc, 
       PO180M1.POORDT AS OrderDate, PO180M2.PHUNCT AS UnitCost
FROM PO180M1, PO180M2 
WHERE PO180M1.POORNO = PO180M2.PHORNO 
ORDER BY PartNo, OrderDate DESC
```

Comment: This is known as a [tag:greatest-n-per-group] problem, of which there are _many_ existing solutions.  Can we get some sample data?  Mostly to know where there may be duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost got it. With any aggregates, `Max()`, `Min()`, `Avg()`, `Count()`, `Sum()`, a `GROUP BY` clause is required listing the "level" columns which usually are indicator fields (names, categories, types).

Also, you will leave out a level column that you are trying to run an aggregate, here being `POORDT`. Finally, you will not be able to `ORDER BY` the very aggregated field but only the group fields listed.

```
SELECT PO180M2.PHPPN AS PartNo, (PO180M2.PHVNPD || ' ' || PO180M2.PHVNP2) AS PartDesc, 
       PO180M2.PHUNCT AS UnitCost, Max(PO180M1.POORDT) As MaxPOORDT
FROM PO180M1 
INNER JOIN PO180M2 ON PO180M1.POORNO = PO180M2.PHORNO 
GROUP BY PO180M2.PHPPN, (PO180M2.PHVNPD || ' ' || PO180M2.PHVNP2), PO180M2.PHUNCT
ORDER BY PartNo
```

By the way, I noticed you used the older syntax of table joins listing tables in `FROM` clause with a `WHERE` clause. I changed it to an `INNER JOIN` with `ON` which I believe is compliant with DB2.

Comment: How can i get the first row out of each group instead of the entire group?

Comment: Not quite understanding. You can add a `DISTINCT` after `SELECT` to your earlier query but it should yield the same as this `GROUP BY` query just without the `Max(POORDT)`. If records repeat adjust group fields.

Comment: Good catch. If OP intends for better performance, consider breaking apart concatenated column.